# Nodemailer works on local, but not works without displayunlockcaptcha on Netlify

Tags: smtp, gmail, nodemailer, netlify, netlify-function

I have an email verification feature through nodemailer in node server.
It works on localhost, but not works on Netlify once it's deployed.
Here are my codes.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       host: "smtp.gmail.com",
       port: 465,
       secure: true,
       auth: {
           user: "mygmail@gmail.com",
           pass: "mypassword",
       },
});
```

On live server, it occurs an error that -
Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14  534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 195sm513587qkd.6 - gsmtp

I enabled "Less secure apps" in my google account.

And allowed https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha as well

it worked a while, but since I cleared browser histories, it didn't work again.

So I allowed displayunlockcaptch again, it worked.

It means I should allow displayunlockcaptcha every times.

Is there any way to keep allowing it? Or any other way?

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is that Netlify doesn't have a static IP. So when the ip changes, Google blocks you again. Using oauth may be a solution .